# Ruby app tells me to install 2.5.1 but its already installed

Tags: ruby, apache, passenger

Yesterday I had managed to restore a Ruby App on my linux server, today this app has stopped working, I am not sure why.

When i try to access ive got

```
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

The only clue I have is that when I navigate to the project directory through the console, I get the message;

```
Required ruby-2.5.1 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install' ruby-2.5.1 "'
```

However when I check the version of ruby ​​installed, with

```
ruby ​​-v:

ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

Any help on whats goin on?

Comment: probably a path issue.  You probably have a system ruby but the application is searching for rvm installed ruby.

Comment: Any recommendations? its ubuntu 18 using apache passenger, can you help me?

Comment: As you can figure i'm completely new to this

Comment: Well that will depend on the application - no crystal ball here.  You should post minimal working example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  We need to know the application, the code, the configuration, etc.